# Save two arrays with Numpy.savetxt into a .csv file, with a column for each array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have difficulties with `numpy.savetxt`. Particularly, I have two arrays with `B` created by the following command `np.arrrange(2000,5000)`, while `print(A)` is like `[0 2 1 ... 0 1 2]` and I would like to save both of them in a single csv file with the format array `B` in the first column and array `A` in the second column:

```
2000 0

2001 2

2002 1
```

I tried with the command `np.savetxt('output.csv', np.c_[B,A], delimeter=',')` but what I get is that both `B` and `A` are in the same column:

```
2000+0

2001+2

2002+1
```

May you be so kind to tell me my mistake and a possible solution?

Edit
I managed to get a solution thanks to FHTMitchell, the only thing that is not working now is that I don't get the 0:
My output is the following

`2000

2001,2

2002,1`

I tried with

`res = np.c_[B,A] 
output = res.astype(int)
np.savetxt('out.csv', output, fmt='%d', delimiter=',')`

But I still don't get the zeros.

Comment: Looks like you used '+' as the delimiter.  Also did you look at the `np.c_` result before saving?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution worked fine for me, although I needed to set the `fmt` specifier to `'%d'` for integers. What version of numpy are you on (for me `np.__version__ == '1.14.1'`)?

Anyway, here is a possible solution with more standard numpy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0, 2, 1])
B = np.arange(2000, 2003)

np.savetxt('out.csv', np.column_stack((B, A)), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')
```

Outputs

```
2000,0
2001,2
2002,1
```

Comment: Thank You! I'm using 1.14.2. Your method works well! The only thing is that the outputs is without 0. (i,e 2000 and not 2000,0) I tried to use astype(int) but doesn't seem to change the output.

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli Can you update the question with this new information and what your current output is?